# What about Rye Gerhardt shoe in the tree?

Tags: plot-explanation, fargo-tv

I am curious about Rye Gerhardt loosing his shoe in the first episode of Season 2, and it appears in a branch of a tree.

Do you know what happened?

Is it possible to be related to the UFO appearance?

Comment: Sometimes articles of clothing are used in quickly-shot struggle scenes for dramtic effect.  http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/LosingAShoeInTheStruggle

Answer (score 7):

> Is it possible to be related to the UFO appearance?

## Not really....but tangentially.

Rye was *standing in the middle of the road* and got hit by a vehicle which knocked his shoe off from the force of the impact... it happens in real life too.

Of course, the reason he was standing in the road was that he was distracted by the appearance of the UFO...but the UFO and shoe aren't really related.